# Remove Magento 2 AdminHTML theme

Tags: magento2, adminhtml, theme

I currently have a theme applied to my magento admin section which I would like to remove and go back to default but I am unsure how to do this.

I'm guessing that it's not simply a case of deleting the theme files and I would like to not break the site.

Can anyone suggest how to safely remove the theme and do back to the default Magento 2 admin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far I can tell, admin theme are not like front end theme.

I really guess you can safely remove files of your custom admin html theme), and then :

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

To uninstall a Magento Admin theme, you must also remove it from your component’s dependency injection configuration, /etc/di.xml.

Some official docs about it :
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/frontend-dev-guide/themes/admin_theme_apply.html

Comment: Hi. That seems to have done the trick. Thanks. Had to delete it from the database too but couldn't find it in "app / etc / di.xml". Doesn't seem to have had any adverse effects though.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow this process.

- Assign default theme in admin panel.
- Delete custom theme entry from `theme` table.
- Delete theme directory from `app/design/adminhtml`.
- Run `php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy && php bin/magento cache:clean`